# Changing theme removes page content in dashboard's post main editor

Tags: content

My client's old site used some theme X. I created a child theme Y of some parent commercial theme Z.

When viewing the admin page of a certain page while old theme X is activated, I see its content in main editor. But if I switch to my child theme Y, content is gone: http://goo.gl/czGLAa (top: the page viewed with new theme activated, bottom: same page viwed when old theme is activated)

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The new theme uses a theme builder called Waves Page Builder. Many premium themes use page builders to allow non-technical users to add complex items to pages, such as sliders, columns, etc. The new theme is likely overriding the content in the main post editor in favor of the page builder.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case: I deactivated the page builder in question (now the page builder section is gone) but the content is still gone... And appears when switching back to old theme